# Debugging stack overflow in C?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, stack-overflow

I have this sample program which when compiled with fstack-protector-all gives a stack smashing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


int func(int* value)
{
    uint8_t port = 1;

    *value = port; //Canary value changes at this point when seen in GDB

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    uint16_t index = 0;

    int ret = func((int*)&index);

}
```

I don't understand what is wrong with the line. Is any typecasting required?

Comment: Even though I see answers coming for this question, I am unable to reproduce any error.I did `gcc -fstack-protector yourcode.c`. And it runs fine.

Comment: Sorry the flag is -fstack-protector-all

Comment: I tried that too. Still compiles just fine. And runs fine too.

Comment: That's strange. I get a smash with the all flag. See if canary value changes in gdb.

Comment: Another nice example on how to shoot yourself in the foot by uselessly casting around.

Answer (score 6):

It's because the size of `int` and the size of `int16_t` are different. The size of `int` is (usually) 32 bits (four bytes) while `int16_t` is 16 bits (two bytes).

So when you write an `int` to a `int16_t` variable you write two bytes too many, and leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (and in this case will "smash" the stack).

The problem is more specifically because you call the function with a pointer to `index` which is a 16-bit variable, but the function expects (and uses its argument) as a 32-bit variable. You should not do the cast there in the call, as that *hides* the problem but doesn't solve it. It doesn't matter that you only write an 8-bit value to the dereference pointer inside the function, the destination is still a 32-bit variable and the compiler will convert the 8-bit value to a 32-bit value before writing to memory.

Comment: I think in this line ' *value = port; ', a uint8_t is written to an int. Where is int written to u16?

Comment: But where does he write an int to a int16_t ?

Comment: @IDK You pass a pointer to an `int16_t` to the function, but the function expects a pointer to `int`. There's the problem. I assume you added the typecast in the call just because you got warnings about that? Warnings are often a sign of you doing something you should not be doing, hiding it with a typecast just *hides* the problem but doesn't solve it.

Comment: @IDK: since `value` is an `int *`, the `uint8_t` is converted to `int` before being stored.

Answer (score 2):

Since the type of `index` is `uint16_t`, only 16 bits are allocated for it. By casting the address of `index` to `int*`, you are pretending you have access to more than 16 bits -- 32 bits in most cases.

In

```
*value = port;
```

you are trying to set the value in those bits that haven't been allocated. Since unauthorized memory gets used in that line, any thing can happen after that.